# Fist Button Click missed after screen initialised with Rxjava kotlin class

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, buttonclick

I am using **RxJava** with **Kotlin** in my **Android** Application. to avoid multiple continues clicks on a button i handled like below with Rxava by using **throttleFirst** method.

```
compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

@OnClick(R.id.f1rst_button)
fun onFirstButtonClick(view: View) {
    Log.d("capture click event started")
    compositeDisposable.add(RxView.clicks(view).throttleFirst(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                Log.d("capture click event accepted")
               performFirstButtonClick()
            })
}
```

But, Always, First click of the button after screen initialised is missing. its working as expected from 2nd click onwards.
For ex : launch the screen -> wait for screen to load -> click on Button and wait for action -> here button click event is triggered & print in the log statement  `Log.d("capture click event started")`. But `performFirstButtonClick()` is not triggered and respective log also not printed for 1st time click after screen loaded.
please let me know if i am doing something wrong (or) any alternative solution.

**`More Info`** : just to provide more info i am editing this.
This Button is in a DialogFragment.
flow is like below
Started Activity A

-> on a button click in **Activity A**, started **Activity B** (which contains a **WebView** with **form**)

-> **Activity C** will be opened when user clicked on Button in the **Form** from **Activity B** via **JavascriptInterfaceBridge**

-> **Activity C** contains a button(**onFirstButtonClick**).

Here Activity A & Activity B are **Java** files & Activity C is a **kotlin** file. the issue is related to that button in the **Activity C** .

Answer (score 0):

First of all you creating new RX subscription on every button click, this is unnecessary.
You don't need using ButterKnife here, just after view creation (e.g.`onCreate()`) set on click listener with:

```
RxView.clicks(view)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe{
       // Handle click listener
}.also { 
 // Just once add subscription to Composite Disposable container
 compositeDisposable.add(it) 
}
```

Second thing, if you want avoid multiple continues clicks, I suggest operator debounce `.debounce(400,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`. With this operator you will throttle clicks in period between multiple clicks.